# Display MySQL query result as XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to create a PowerShell script that connects to a MySQL instance, runs a query and parses the result as XML. I am starting from here:

```bsh
Param(
  [Parameter(
  Mandatory = $true,
  ParameterSetName = '',
  ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [string]$Query
)

$MySQLAdminUserName = 'adminuser'
$MySQLAdminPassword = 'password'
$MySQLDatabase = 'mysql'
$MySQLHost = '192.168.10.126'
$ConnectionString = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" + $MySQLAdminUserName + ";pwd=" + $MySQLAdminPassword + ";database="+$MySQLDatabase

try {
  [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
  $Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
  $Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
  $Connection.Open()

  $Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
  $DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
  $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
  $DataSet.Tables[0] 
} catch {
  Write-Host "ERROR : Unable to run query : $query `n$Error[0]"
} finally {
  $Connection.Close()
}
```

The script returns the tables, but I cannot get it anyhow to format the results as XML. Can you please help me with this? All the queries I intend to run will display 2 columns.

Comment: What have you tried to format the output as XML? What didn't work? How excactly did it not work? What would your desired output look like in the first place?

Comment: The format should be for PRTG monitoring:
<prtg>
  <result>
    <channel>First channel</channel>
    <value>10</value>
  </result>
  <result>
    <channel>Second channel</channel>
    <value>20</value>
  </result>
</prtg>

Each table row will have channel name on first column and value on the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something this simple full-blown XML construction might be overkill. You could simply insert your table values into string templates, like this:

```
$results = $DataSet.Tables[0] | ForEach-Object {
  '<result><channel>{0}</channel><value>{1}</value></result>' -f $_.col1, $_.col2
}

$prtg = "<prtg>{0}</prtg>" -f (-join $results)
```

Replace `col1` and `col2` with the actual field names.

Comment: thank you! seems to do exactly what I need. I will try it tomorrow in a custom sensor.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
$DataSet.Tables[0].WriteXML('c:\temp\result.xml')
```

or this

```
[xml] $xml=$DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-XML -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, working with temp files is not an option because I will have a lot of these scripts running at the same time. I would need to directly get the XML result. It will be user with PRTG monitoring. The query will return a table with 2 columns: on the first column there is the channel name and on the second the value. 

https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/exe_script_advanced_sensor

Comment: you can use a random file name for xml, then load xml a modify like you want after loaded

Comment: try this too $DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-XML -NoTypeInformation

Comment: the ConvertTo-XML just gives me this:


xml                                                Objects
---                                                 -------
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"     Objects

Comment: the .WriteXML gives the exact answer I am looking for, but I want not to use temporary files.

Comment: Why you dont want use temporary file? What is your problem ?